# For every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, and the Taylor series $Tf (x)$ of $f(x) = (1 + x)^a$ about $x_0 = 0$ and its region of convergence.

Tags: calculus

I got stuck on this question

> For every $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$, find the Taylor series of $f(x) = (1 + x)^a$ about $x_0 = 0$ and its region of convergence.

I was trying to derive those elements to get the series but I did not know how to compute it with a. any ideas ? :)
thank you

Comment: [Here's a tutorial in MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: I don't see a question here...

Comment: i have to find the taylor series

Comment: @gal I think you have a typo. It should say "find the Taylor ..." , but you have "and the Taylor".

Comment: $a=\alpha{}{}$ ?

Answer (score 0):

$$
f'(x) = a(1+x)^{a - 1},\qquad
f'(0) = a;$$
$$f''(x) = a(a - 1)(1+x)^{a - 2},\qquad
f''(0) = a(a - 1)
$$
$$\cdots$$
$$f^{(n)}(0) = a(a - 1)\cdots(a - n + 1)$$
Defining
$$
\binom{a}{n} = \frac{a(a - 1)\cdots(a - n + 1)}{n!},\qquad
\binom{a}{0} = 1,
$$
the Taylor series is
$$f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty\binom{a}{n}x^n$$
with radius of convergence $1$ (why?).